# Setting up touch driver to run through service

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, services

We are trying to integrate a touch panel to our Debian system.

[Touch driver (General touch)](http://www.generaltouch.com/upload/file/linuxgtusbdriver_i386.rar)

I am trying to run this application in Linux service.Below are the steps which i followed

**Driver installtion**

```
cp -rf Gentouch_S/ /usr/local/Gentouch_S/
cp -f 10-evdev.conf /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf
cp -f 69-gentouch.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/69-gentouch.rules
```

**Setting touch in service**

```
 cp genTouchService /etc/init.d/genTouchSevice
 chmod 755 /etc/init.d/genTouchSevice
 update-rc.d genTouchSevice defaults
```

**Script details for :/etc/init.d/genTouchSevice**

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/genTouchSevice
#
# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
case "$1" in
  start)
    logger "Gentouch module started by service"
    /usr/local/Gentouch_S/GT_service start
    ;;
  stop)
    logger "Gentouch module stopped by service"
    /usr/local/Gentouch_S/GT_service stop
    ;;
  restart)
    logger "Gentouch module restarted by service"
    /usr/local/Gentouch_S/GT_service restart
    ;;

  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/genTouchSevice {start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

On doing this, I was pretty sure that the application started via service during boot up.
verified by log(2014 Aug 20 00:58:24::logger:: Gentouch module started by service)

Even though the service started, When i touch my screen i dont see any touch events (No movement in pointer position too)

So, Just tried restarting touch driver in below scenarios:

**1 . service genTouchSevice restart**

```
No effeci, Still there was no touch event detection
```

**2./usr/local/Gentouch_S/ST_service restart**

```
My application was able to sense the touch events.
```

What is the error.Unable to find it